# trying to get location from address using google api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have this javascript in my html what i want to do here is to get a map representation given the location

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
function getmaploc() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    geocoder.geocode( 'cairo', function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    });
}
</script>

<body onload="getmaploc()">
  <div id="map_canvas"  style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
</body>
```

I cant figure out whats wrong with this any help??

Comment: Please format your code, many people (me included) will not read code that is not well-formatted

Comment: fixed it im sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: Reformatted it for you, your *fix* was still not very readable. Here's another tip: "it doesn't work" without an error message makes it harder for others to help.

Comment: Thanks alot the code now looks even cleaner :D problem fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple errors,

- a omitted brace
- initialize the map first
- geocode() expects a GeocoderRequest-object as argument

---

fixed code:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function getmaploc() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom : 8,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    geocoder.geocode({
        address : 'cairo'
    }, function(results, status) {
        console.log(results);
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                position : results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: please don't complain about my indentation, I like it ^^

Comment: Thanks Alot fixed the problem Dr.Molle